# GAE and JRuby HTTP connections

Tags: api, google-app-engine, jruby

I want to start to a new JRuby project on GAE but I read that GAE does not allow you to create new sockets. I want to use some API that have to work over HTTP connect like Garb (Google Analytics client). Has anyone managed to use any API over HTTP on GAE?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[java.net.URLConnection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) works, but any API using different `java.net` parts needs to be recoded in terms of `URLConnection` (if that's even possible -- many APIs won't; RESTful ones however should be workable).